# Laravel 8 how to implement whereNot

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

In Laravel 9 you have a new method called `whereNot` but not in Laravel 8. I cannot upgrade to Laravel 9 right now so I am looking for an alternative solution.

The goal is to exclude products that both have zero in `stock` and `stock_date` older than one month. The trick is both conditions should be considered or they are disregarded. So a product can have zero `stock` and less than one month old and still be part of the result.

Here is how I would probably do it in Laravel 9:

```
$query = Product::select('id')
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->where('type', 1)
    ->whereNot(function ($q) {
        $q->where('stock', 0)
           ->where('stock_date', '<', Carbon::now()->subMonths(1));
    });
```

I would probably write this in pure MySQL:

```
# The assumption is that the current date is: 2022-10-31
SELECT
    id
FROM
    products
WHERE
    status = 1
    AND type = 1
    AND NOT (stock = 0 AND stock_date < '2022-09-31')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you cannot use new features, which is understandable, then you should invert your query like so:

```
$query = Product::select('id')
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->where('type', 1)
    ->where(function ($q) {
        $q->where('stock', '<>', 0)
           ->where('stock_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonths(1));
    })
    ->get();
```